# Responsive Design or Fluid Grid System

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a full responsive web template using bootstrap 2.3.2. As you are fully aware bootstrap is offering both Responsive Design and Fluid Grid System systems.To be honest I am kind of confused here? what is the different between these too? Which one has a better performance?
I have ssen some example using

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

Can I use this in Responsive Design format as well? Is it going be different than using simply

```
 <div class="row">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While similar concepts, Fluid Grids and Responsive are slightly different.  In the most basic terms, a fluid grid changes it's width in proportion to the width of the browser, while a Responsive system changes the widths at specific pixel intervals.  You can have a mix of Fluid and Responsive, if say you wanted 3 columns when the browser was a medium or large size, but one column on a small screen, and wanted the columns proportionally spaced.

Answer (score 0):

Fluid grid implies the elements in the page take up the same percentage of space irrespective of the width of the page. So the elements shrink/grow appropriately if a page is maximised or shrinked. Responsive UI on the other hand refers to the fact that the UI renders differently depending upon the device. So if a page supports and uses responsive UI, it will render differently on a cellphone, tablet and a desktop.

In the example you have, thats an example of a fluid layout. So if you shrink your browser, the page will shrink accordingly. This way the page displays all the elements rather than enabling horizontal and vertical scrolling to see the complete page.

If you now wish to make your design responsive, you should add the classes like .visible-xs, .visible-sm etc. For further examples to responsive UI refer http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities